# Calculate the response time of a particular request made by the firefox browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

How do i Calculate the response time of a particular request made by the firefox browser.

Even i will like to find the response time for chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can track network requests for Chrome using dev network tools and HAR Log.

***manifest.json***

```
{
    "name": "Network Demo",
    "description": "This is a sample for API's available for Network",
    "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "2",
    "permissions": ["experimental"]
}
```

***devtools.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="devtools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***devtool.js***

req in the following code returns [HAR Log](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec) and you can use it for reading content you need; I have used the HAR for [TCP Connection time](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/#timings) here (http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/har-12-spec/#timings)

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function(req) {
    // Displayed sample TCP connection time here
    chrome.experimental.devtools.console.addMessage(
        chrome.experimental.devtools.console.Severity.Log,
        req.timings.connect
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On Firefox you can use the [nsIHttpActivityObserver interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpActivityObserver)